# Fail Maven build if Maven property is not aligned to convention

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Maven properties in `pom.xml` of Java repos have to be aligned to some convention for CI processes to work correctly.

For example:

`<app-name.prop-name-version>X.X.X.X</app-name-version.prop-name-version>`

Is there a way to fail maven builds if maven property is not aligned to convention?

I thought about developing maven plugin from scratch, but is there another way?

Comment: Why do you have a property which is needed for ci ? Can you explain what exactly that is needed for?

Answer (score 5):

Maven Enforcer Plugin exactly does what you need. That has a lot of built-in rules like *Require Property*
According the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html) this rule can enforce the declared property is set and optionally fits for a regex rule.

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-property</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireProperty>
                  <property>app-name.prop-name-version</property>
                  <message>"Project version must be specified."</message>
                  <regex>.*[...]$</regex>
                  <regexMessage>"Invalid format."</regexMessage>
                </requireProperty>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```